# I cannot display the list of countries within the select option: property undefined error vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been working with simple dropdown, and I keep having this error returned https://prnt.sc/1xdusd2 (I solved the prop problem)

then I read a bit more on that specific problem and turns out this happens when vue instance cannot find your property.

But **countries** is there and it is within the instance. I can't understand where I went wrong.

So, the idea is to make the dropdown reactive to the countries data I am getting from api.

data exists only on the parent component and I am sending it as a prop to the child component where I am iterating and displaying within the ooption.

can someone help me what is wrong here specifically

```js
drop down component (child component) 


<template>
<div>
  <select v-for="(country, ) in countries" :key="country">
    <option >{{country.name}} </option>
  </select>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "DropDown",
  props:['countries'],
  data() {
    return {
      selectedOption: null,
    };
  },
};
</script>


parent component ************

<template>
  <div class="step1 flex flex-col">
    <h1 class="self-start mb-5">Шаг 1.</h1>
    <div class="flex justify-center ">
      <h3 class="text-white font-medium text-xl">Выберите страну</h3>
      <div class="mx-5" >
        <DropDown :countries="countries" />
        {{}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//import Button from "./UI/Button.vue";
import DropDown from "./UI/DropDown.vue";
export default {
  name: "Step1",
  components: {
    DropDown: DropDown,
    //Button: Button,
  },
  
  data() {
    return{
      // countries: [
      //   {
      //       id: "RU",
      //       name: "Россия"
      //   },
      //   {
      //       id: "DE",
      //       name: "Германия"
      //   },
      //   {
      //       id: "EE",
      //       name: "Эстония"
      //   }
      // ],
    }
  },
  methods:{
    async fetchCountry (){
      const res = await fetch('api/countries')
      let countries = await res.json();
      return countries
    }
  },

  created() {
   
  }
};
```

Comment: Why did you `comment` countries in parent data ?

Answer (score 0):

Vue tries to load your country data before the api fetch has finished, to bypass this add an `v-if="countries"` in your `<select v-for="(country, ) in countries" :key="country">`, then vue will only try to load it if countries is not null

Comment: thank you so much  for helping me out, I cant seem to get it to work so far, but at least now the problem is with api, not with my code I hope or so it says in the console.  I'll update as soon as I get to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to have countries in your data in order for it to work in the template, try this in your parent:

```
import DropDown from "./UI/DropDown.vue";

export default {
  name: "Step1",

  components: {
    DropDown,
  },
  
  data() {
    return {
      countries: [],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async fetchCountry() {
      const res = await fetch('api/countries')
      this.countries = await res.json();
    }
  },
};
```

And this in your child

```
<template>
  <select v-model="selectedOption">
    <option
      v-for="country in countries"
      :key="country.name"
      :value="country.name"
    >
      {{ country.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DropDown",

  props: {
    countries: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      selectedOption: null,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```